# Matrix Norm Inequality $\lVert A\rVert_\infty \leq \sqrt{n} \lVert A\rVert_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

So I'm trying to prove that

$\lVert A\rVert_\infty \leq \sqrt{n} \lVert A\rVert_2$.

I've written the right hand side in terms of rows, but this method doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Where else should I go?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 6):

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n_\infty$. We know that $\Vert y\Vert_\infty\leq \Vert y\Vert_2\leq\sqrt{n}\Vert y\Vert_\infty$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, so
$$
\Vert A(x)\Vert_\infty\leq\Vert A(x)\Vert_2\leq\Vert A\Vert_2\Vert x\Vert_2\leq\Vert A\Vert_2\sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_\infty
$$
Since $x\in \mathbb{R}^n_\infty$ is arbitrary
$$
\Vert A\Vert_\infty\leq\sqrt{n}\Vert A\Vert_2
$$

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb{R}_{\infty}^n$ mean?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\max$ norm

Comment: @Norbert
Isn't this proof missing the fact that,

$\{x \in X: ||x||_{\infty} = 1\} \subseteq \{x \in X: ||x||_{2} = 1\}? $

Comment: @TobiasRieper there are different equivalent defintions of operator norm. I use this one
$$\Vert A\Vert=\sup\{\Vert A(x)\Vert / \Vert x\Vert : x\neq 0\}$$

Comment: @Norbert , Hello thanks for the reply. But I'm confused as to how that follow in the proof, we have that:
$ \Vert A(x)\Vert_\infty\leq\Vert A(x)\Vert_2,$
but how does that imply
$||Ax||_{\infty} ~ / ~ ||x||_{\infty} \le ||Ax||_{2} ~ / ~||x||_{2}? $

Comment: In general $\forall x \; \Vert\ T(x) \Vert \leq C \Vert x\Vert$ implies $\Vert T\Vert \leq C$

Comment: @Norbert, I see now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $A=(A_1,\dots,A_n)^\mathrm{T}$ with $A_i$ being the $i$-th row of the matrix, let $A_j$ be the row for which 
$$
\lVert A\rVert_\infty = \max_{1\leq i\leq n }\lVert A_i\rVert_1 = \lVert A_j\rVert_1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \left|A_{i,j}\right|
$$
Then
$$
n\lVert A\rVert_2^2 = n\sum_{i=1}^n \lVert A_i\rVert_2^2 \geq  n\lVert A_j\rVert_2^2 \geq \lVert A_j\rVert_1^2 = \lVert A\rVert_\infty^2
$$
where the last inequality is "standard" (relation between 1 and 2-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, can be proven with Cauchy-Schwarz).

Comment: I think $\|A\|_2$ denotes the operator 2-norm $\|A\|_2=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$, not the Frobenius norm (vector 2-norm) $\|A\|_F^2=\operatorname{trace}(A^\ast A)=\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2$.

Comment: What justifies the first equality on the second line?

Comment: @Chad [The definition of $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entrywise%22_matrix_norms) (assuming this notation is indeed the one the OP use, as for matrices $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ is commonly used for several norms)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm attempting to prove the same inequality that the OP posted, but interpreting $||\cdot||_p$ as the [induced operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms).  Perhaps I'll post a separate question.

Comment: Yes, this particular answer will not help for that...

Comment: Why the downvote (6 years later, with no comment)?